# mongoose remove not working [findByIdAndRemove]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to remove object by id , but get error "[TypeError: Cannot read property '$set' of undefined]" what can be wrong?

```
var remove = function(req, res, next) {

var id = req.urlParams.id ;

req.urlParams.model.findByIdAndRemove(id,function(err, doc){
console.log(err);
if (err) { return sendError(res,err) }

var data = JSON.stringify(req.body);
...
}
```

id is initialized and object with that id exist

Answer (score 3):

It seems a little strange that you're looking for your mongoose model in the urlParams. I would have expected something more like

```
function remove(req, res, model, next){
    model.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err)....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your whole code but, if your goal is remove object that _id has req.urlParams.id, following code would help you.

```
var remove = function(req, res, next) {
yourModel.remove({_id: req.urlParams.id},function(err, doc){
console.log(err);

if (err) { return sendError(res,err) }
else{ //do something}
}
```

I have a question : `console.log(req.urlParams.id)` work?
if you could type your code detail, I can help you more

Answer (score 0):

var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId((req.urlParams.id).trim());

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Remove using id:

```js
Model.findByIdAndRemove(id).exec();
```